# MVC RedirectAction From Create To Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

```
         <HttpPost()> _
        Function Create(ByVal cbadata As CBAData) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.CBADatas.Add(cbadata)
                '    db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Edit", "CBAData", cbadata)
            End If
        End Function


    '
    ' GET: /CBAData/Edit/5

    Function Edit(Optional ByVal id As Integer = Nothing) As ActionResult
        Dim cbadata As CBAData = db.CBADatas.Find(id)
        If IsNothing(cbadata) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        ViewBag.idCustomer = New SelectList(db.Customers, "id", "Name", cbadata.idCustomer)

        Return View(cbadata)
    End Function

    '
    ' POST: /CBAData/Edit/5

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function Edit(ByVal cbadata As CBAData) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.Entry(cbadata).State = EntityState.Modified
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End If

        ViewBag.idCustomer = New SelectList(db.Customers, "id", "Name", cbadata.idCustomer)
        Return View(cbadata)
    End Function
```

I'm trying to use the Create view as a launch point for creating a new CBAData item. I will want them to select some simple information and then continue on to the Edit view, where the data will eventually be saved if the model is valid.

The code above doesn't navigate correctly. When it gets to the Find method on db.CBADatas it doesnt exist in the list. Is this possible?

Is it because everything including the context is getting disposed and recreated for the Edit View?

Comment: What is `db.CBADatas`? An entity framework repository? Your `db.SaveChanges` is commented out. You're not saving anything so it's not there when you call `Find`.

Comment: Yes db.CBADatas is an entity framework repository for objects called CBAData. If you read above I mentioned that I dont want to save the changes to the database until the edit action has been taken.

Comment: In the end I just used a session variable and called RedirectToAction("Edit", cbadata)

Answer (score 0):

call the Edit action like

```
<HttpPost()> _
    Function Create(ByVal cbadata As CBAData) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            db.CBADatas.Add(cbadata)
            '    db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Edit", "CBAData", new{ id = cbadata})
        End If
    End Function
```